# Is calling clone() a good option when local variable and instance variable is same in constructor

Tags: java

```java
class X{

    private String[] filename;

    public X(String[] filename){
        this.filename = filename.clone();
    }
}
```

Is calling clone() is good option when local variable and instance variable is same in constructor.

Comment: What do you mean by same? Same Object Instance?

Comment: What are you achieving out of this? A parameter can be directly assigned to the class variable!

Comment: you should understand this has no influence at all. Yes, they have the same name, but only if you use them through the (this.) reference, it's the instance variable

Comment: It is no better or worse than other options.  (The fact that your field name and local variable name are the same make zero difference.  Why would it?)

Comment: That's one of the reasons for this `this`-operator... If a variable name is ambiguous, you can distinguish by `this` (in case one of them is a class attribute and the other one a parameter): `this.filename = filename;`, no need for cloning...

Answer (score 0):

This depends on what you actually want to achieve. Since the argument `filename` is in fact a reference to the object that the caller created, whoever called `new X(filename)` has a reference to the `filename` array and can further modify it.

1) If you don't mind that code outside your control can change the array, you can just assign `this.filename = filename`.

2) If you want to make sure no other code can mess up with your array than cloning can help. Keep in mid though the new array will still hold reverences to the very same objects the original one had. Thus it will not help much if the array elements are mutable. For example if you had `Foo[]` instead of `String[]`, someone having a reference to any given `Foo` can modify it outside of your control.

3) If by any chance you decided to use a single element array instead of `String` only because arrays have the `clone` method, then your approach does not buy you anything.

Comment: *"Arguments are passed by reference"* — this is somewhat inaccurate in the context of Java. [Java is always pass-by-value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value) – it's just that the values themselves are references.

Comment: I didn't mean to claim Jawa is "pass-by-reference". But I see how my answer can be misinterpreted this way so I updated it. Hope it's more clear now. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: This looks better to me :-)

Comment: If you don't mind that code outside your control can change the array, you can just assign this.filename = filename. -- 

if I go with this option its showing 1 vulnerabilities in sonar.